# Microsoft ACE.oledb.16 is not registered, but it is

Tags: vb.net, isam

I have searched high and low for this situation... and it's annoying me.

I am coding in VB.net 2019 and am trying to import an Excel spreadsheet. I ran the code on Monday and it worked great! I run the code on Tuesday... and it fails.

The ACE OLEDB v.16 is installed and it worked, but now the app is claiming it's not registered.

I had the same thing happen to me when trying to do a bulk insert on SQL Server (2019). It ran once on Friday, and on Monday, no love.

That's #1... #2...

Remember how it worked on Monday, first thing yesterday, I tried to install it on my production server to test it. The server does not have Excel or Office installed, due to the obvious licensing costs and the lack of available disc space... I administer the server, don't maintain the hardware, so there is no control there.

However, I installed the ACE driver, 32 bit, and it runs... until it could not find an installable ISAM. Don't tell me to install the access driver, it's there... so what is this ISAM thing about?

I am getting worried that my site security is so dang blasted smart that it saw my actions and blocked them. sigh.

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? *`Microsoft ACE.OleDb.16` is not registered* or *Could not find an installable ISAM*? If the former, is your app is targeting x64?

Comment: *"what is this ISAM thing"*. What did you not understand about the information you found when you copied the error message into a search engine? You did search for information yourself first, didn't you?

Comment: I thought I was clear. It worked on Monday. Failed on Tuesday, same machine, same code, same configuration.

The server, it just doesn't want to access the ISAM for some reason. 

In both cases, we are told to install the ACE download. I have done that. I will try again. Seems like the definition of insanity.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Also specify what kind of project you're using. Whether you're using .NET Framework or .NET, as well as, the version number. What operating system are you running your program on?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution